# React Native: Can you detect when app is closed down, as opposed to backgrounded?

Tags: javascript, react-native, foreground, background-foreground, appstats

In my React Native app I'm using [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) to try and detect when the app goes to the background, vs when it's completely closed down. I want to trigger separate functions for each. But from their documentation it looks like when the app is backgrounded *or* closed, the same thing happens: it goes from `active` to `inactive` and then to `background`.

Is there any way to trigger separate functions when the app is closed vs backgrounded?

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code:

```
if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  AppState.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    // do something when the app closed
  });
}

AppState.addEventListener('change', onAppStateChange);

async function onAppStateChange(state: string) {
  if (state === 'inactive') {
    // do something when the app closed
  } else if (state === 'background') {
    // do something when the app minimized
  } else if (state === 'active') {
    // do something when the app opened
  }
}
```